# Reddit API ios modhash/cookie issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, api, reddit

Im' trying to submit to Reddit via my iOS app. I can login fine and am sent back a modhash and a cookie which I save via `NSUserDefaults`.

The issue is when I post the data I keep getting "USER_REQUIRED" as the response, even though I have included the modhash in the post and set my session cookie. I have even included the following in my app delegate:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]
    setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

But it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
-(void) post {

    NSString *modhash2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  
        objectForKey:@"modhash"];

    NSString *urlString = [NSString 
        stringWithFormat:@"https://ssl.reddit.com/api/submit"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:redditCookie forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *httpBody = [NSString stringWithFormat
        :@" ?uh=%@&kind=link&url=%@&sr=%@&title=%@&r=%@&api_type=json",
        modhash2,
        @"www.google.com",
        @"test",
        @"Google.com",
        @"test"];


    [request setHTTPBody:[httpBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

    NSURLResponse* response;
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSData* result = [NSURLConnection
        sendSynchronousRequest:request
        returningResponse:&response
        error:&error];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
        JSONObjectWithData:result
        options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
        error:nil];

    NSDictionary *responseJSON = [json valueForKey:@"json"];
    NSLog(@"RETURN: %@",responseJSON);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Two quick things. 1) I don't believe you need the leading space and '?' in your POST body. 2) Where is the 'redditCookie' variable being set and what is in it?

Comment: In reagrds to 1) You are right, not sure why that was there but didn't help removing. 2)The cookie is being set in the 'login' method that occurs before this. I can have checked the cookie and modhash when I login and when I get to this method and they are the same.
The cookie contains "13313571,2012-11-11T23:39:54,c9f7c4eb02b3c486f7821dc9774a65ef05ed96b3"
Hopefully this helps in some way!